# copy Excel chart to placeholder in Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy an Excel chart to a specific placeholder in Powerpoint. I have named the placeholder using the following code

```
Sub NameShape()
Dim Name$
On Error GoTo AbortNameShape
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Shapes Selected"
    Exit Sub
End If
Name$ = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
Name$ = InputBox$("Give this shape a name", "Shape Name", Name$)
If Name$ <> "" Then
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = Name$
End If
Exit Sub
AbortNameShape:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

In Excel I have come as far as this:

```
Sub CreateNewReport()
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim w!, h!, t!, l!
Dim Chart As Chart


Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\...\Report.pptm")
Set Chart = Worksheets("Analysts").ChartObjects("Chart 2")
Set PPSlide = pptPres.Slides(4)
'PPSlide.Shapes("Analyst.Forecasts").Copy
Set pptShape = pptPres.Slides(4).Shapes(4)
 With pptShape
    w = .Width
    h = .Height
    l = .Left
    t = .Top
  End With
pptShape.Parent.Paste
  With Selection
    .Width = w
    .Height = h
    .Left = l
    .Top = t
    End With
ppt.Shape.Delete
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to take it from here? I can't quite figure out how to define the chart I want to copy and how to paste & replace the shep in Powerpoint. Ideally I would like to replace it with the metafile of the chart, but a picture is ok as well.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

i use this code to make ppt from Excel and paste in placeHolder;

```
Nr = 2

'Verifique os graficos nos arquivos
    For Each Grf In E.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Grf.Copy
        Sld.Shapes.Placeholders(Nr).Select msoCTrue
        P.ActivePresentation.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
       Nr = Nr + 1
    Next Grf

End If
```